# A verb that means "to both create and save something"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes in computer programming, I write a function that performs both the action of (non-trivially) creating something and then also the action of saving that same thing created. I'm just wondering if there happens to be a short, single verb that captures both.

(I didn't think that the other questions on this site about creating and updating/editing quite matched what I'm looking for.)

Comment: *Establish*? *Found*?

Comment: You could borrow from the culinary realm: jamming.

Comment: "Instantiate" and "generate" come to mind. Neither suggestion explicitly evokes the notion of saving an element; that's calling for a new word!